# How to make function parameter constant in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

What I want to do is to use as many immutable variables as possible, thus reducing the number of moving parts in my code. I want to use "var" and "let" only when it's necessary.

This won't work:

```
function constParam(const a){
    alert('You want me to '+a+'!');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Function parameters will stay mutable bindings (like `var`) in ES6, there's nothing you can do against that. Probably the best solution you get is to destructure the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in a `const` initialisation:

```
function hasConstantParameters(const a, const b, const c, …) { // not possible
    …
}
```

```
function hasConstantParameters() {
    const [a, b, c, …] = arguments;
    …
}
```

Notice that this function will have a different arity (`.length`), if you need that you'll have to declare some placeholder parameters.

Comment: This is actually an interesting solution for that.

If it wasn't so ugly, I would start using it.

Comment: How about `function hasConstantParameters(...args) { const [a, b] = args; };`?

Comment: @BugsBunny That's pretty much the same. However, I don't like the introduction of another identifier (`args`), and I did deliberately put no parameters in the usual place but moved everything into the `const` declaration.

Comment: Making it with dynamic arity ruins the idea of strictness, but yes, this one answers the question correctly!

Comment: @shal The arity is not dynamic, it's just no longer available as the `.length` property of the function object

Comment: @Bergi, you're right, what I mean is that now IDEs like WebStorm cannot infer the number of arguments, to help you with function invocation verification (unless you use JSDoc)

Comment: @Bergi sure, but `arguments`, like `this`, don't exist for short functions `() => {}`

Comment: @Hashbrown In an arrow function, you can also use a rest parameter to get an array of arguments.

Comment: I meant that's what bugs was getting at when you replied `@BugsBunny That's pretty much the same.`; [`If you're writing ES6 compatible code, then rest parameters should be preferred.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: Today, I learned what [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) means :-)

Answer (score 15):

You can't make a parameter `const`. Use it as the initial value of a local variable:

```
function constParam(a) {
    const const_a = a;
    ...
}
```

Note also that `const` is only supported in Internet Explorer as of IE11. See this [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 4):

We can use ES6 destructuring to create constants from params

```js
function test(...args) {
  const [a, b, c] = args;
}
```

Although `const` isn't immutable. If `a` was an object `a.x = 1` would also change `x` on any outter reference to object `a`

I often use `lodash` `cloneDeep` on arguments before doing anything further on them

With Typescript we get type safety using `readonly`, but that's a different topic

Comment: the real win is with arrow functions also cuz `function` has `arguments` parameter but arrow does not

```(...args)=>{ 
  const [a,b,c,...dropped] = args ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to force a parameter to be immutable in JavaScript. You have to keep track of that yourself.

Just write in a style where you happen not to mutate variables. The fact that the language doesn't provide any facilities to *force* you to do so doesn't mean that you can't still do it anyway.

Comment: @QuentinRoy References? Es6 provides ways of declaring constant values, but there is no way to declare a *function parameter* as constant. You can write "function(){ const a = ...; ...}", but you can't write "function(const a){...}".

Comment: You're right sorry I read to fast. I thought you were talking about variable instead of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

**For immutable structures I believe you're looking for [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).**

---

As @Andreas_Gnyp is saying, until ES6 there is no `let` / `const` in JavaScript. (Nor there will be `function(const a) {...}` once ES6 is out and fully supported.) If you want to use `const`, you can either implement your own `const` feature, or start using ES6 notation with help of some third party ES6-to-ES5 compiler, such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

However, bear in mind that `const` in ES6 notation *does not* make the variable immutable. E.g. `const a = [1, 2]; a.push(3);` is a completely valid program and `a` will become `[1, 2, 3]`. `const` will *only* prevent you from reassigning `a`, so that you can't do `a = []` or `a = {}` or whatever once `const a = [1, 2];` already defined (in that particular scope).

```
function hasConstantParameters(...args) {
    const [a, b] = args;
}
```

[Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) will make sure that, when you define `var a = fromJS([1, 2]);` and pass `a` as a function parameter, in the receiving function `a.push(3)` will not affect `a`. Is this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my question. I asked about constant parameters, not about privacy of class members.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

Instead of:

```
function F(const a, const b, const c, const d, const e, const f, const g){ // Invalid Code
    // lorem
    // ipsum
}
```

..Use:

```
function F(){const[a, b, c, d, e, f, g] = arguments;
    // lorem
    // ipsum
}
```

Comment: This is just Bergi's answer without the explanation.

Answer (score -4):

```
function wrapper(i){
    const C=i
    return new Function("a","b", "return a+b+"+C)    
}

f100 = wrapper(100) //ƒ anonymous(a,b/*``*/) {return a+b+100} 
f100(1,2) //OUTPUT 103

f200 = wrapper(200) //ƒ anonymous(a,b/*``*/) {return a+b+200} 
f200(1,2) //OUTPUT 203
```