# Is there a name for a combinator that takes a curried function and a tuple and applies them?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, naming

Has my combinator with the working title `curryTuple` a common name in the functional community?

```js
const curryTuple = f => tuple =>
  foldl(g => x => g(x)) (f) (tuple);

const triple = [x => y => x + y, 0, [1,2,3,4,5]];

const foldl = f => acc => xs => xs.reduce((x, y) => f(x) (y), acc);

console.log(
  curryTuple(foldl) (triple));
```

For obvious reasons only within the dynamically typed community :D

Comment: `foldl` is for arrays or lists, it should not be used on tuples (where the elements have different types). Shudder.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35167310/783743

Answer (score 2):

It's just called `uncurry`.

To paraphrase the title question, it's the combinator that takes a curried function and returns an uncurried function (taking a tuple). A combinator that actually takes both the curried function and the tuple at once (and returns the result of the application) would be `uncurry(uncurry)`.

Comment: You're right, but in a sense it is a variadic uncurry, because it works for any tuple. `variadicUncurry` is still hideous. Any suggestions?

Comment: Considering your comment the function is too dynamically typed anyway..

Comment: If you name your currying function `variadicCurry` instead of `curry`, you'd do the same for `uncurry` of course. Or you just keep their names, make them work with variadic functions, and supply extra `curryN(2)`/`uncurryN(2)` functions for fixed arities. That's the approach Ramda is taking iirc.