# Can a typescript parameter be annotated as const?

Tags: typescript

If I do not want the value of a parameter change within a function scope, is there any way to annotate that with Typescript?

I've tried:

```
function walk(const fileName: string): string[] {
// -----------^
}
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible.

Comment: At least there is an option to make arrays *readonly*: `function foo(bar: readonly number[]) { }`. This feature is not limited to function declarations, and it converts a mutable array to immutable array.

Comment: wwo caveats about that though:
1. It still lets you reassign `bar = ...` (it only prevents `bar[i] = ...` or `bar.pop()`, etc.).
2. `readonly` is shallow so if you have an array of objects instead of simple numbers, it _won't_ prevent `bar[i].whatever = ...`.

Unfortunately immutability is an area where TypeScript is still missing a lot of useful stuff!

Comment: If this became possible everyone would start annotating every single argument as `const` by default to be "safe", like we do with variables, and that could get annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to do it right now, and it may not be, as it is not possible in `ES6` either:

[How to make function parameter constant in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314457/how-to-make-function-parameter-constant-in-javascript)

This workaround doesn't work for TypeScript anyway.

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately, I do not see how the JavaScript workaround can work with Typescript. First, if parameters are not defined, TS complains with `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`,. Second, the tuple syntax results in `error TS2461: Type 'IArguments' is not an array type`.

Comment: @kiewic It doesn't work for TS. I pointed out that is not possible, and using the workaround for TypeScript violates function's argument contract.

Comment: My bad, I missed that part of your answer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @kiewic You didn't. It was edited after you comment, as I saw it may not be clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

It's not supported yet, but you can upvote this feature request & follow it for any updates in the future: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18497

In the meantime your best bet is to use a linter rule to make arguments const by default, like [ESLint's no-param-reassign rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign). In any rare cases where you need an argument to be *not* const, you can either use `eslint-disable-line` each place you reassign it, or wrap the whole function in an `eslint-disable` / `eslint-enable` pair to make *all* its arguments non-const.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't support `const` in the function parameter yet, but you can do `readonly` parameters.

Typescript 3.4 added support for `readonly` arrays and tuples (not objects yet).

Examples:

```js
function foo(arr: readonly string[]) {}
```

or

```js
function foo(pair: readonly [string, string]) {}
```

or

```js
function foo(arr: ReadonlyArray<string>) {}
```

Comment: Are you sure, it seems `Readonly<T>` works with objects too: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlyt

Answer (score 2):

A short workaround with a few extra characters gets close:

```
function fo(args: {x: number,y: string}): void{
    const {x,y} = args;
    x = 2; // Cannot assign to 'x' because it is a constant.ts(2588)
}
function fa(...args: [x: number,y: string]): void{
    const [x,y] = args;
    x = 2; // Cannot assign to 'x' because it is a constant.ts(2588)
}
```

but you can still overwrite using `args.x=2`.