# Function type - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

To define a function type, below example does not allow `const`

```
interface Square{
    readonly color: string;
    readonly area: number;
}

interface compareTo{
    (const v1: Square, const v2: Square): number;  // syntax error      
}
```

How to compare `v1` & `v2` without changing the pointer of an object(`Square`) it is pointing to?

Comment: How is this 'const' supposed to work? Why should function argument be const? It doesn't matter whether it's `const` or not inside function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a typescript parameter be annotated as const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086031/can-a-typescript-parameter-be-annotated-as-const)

Comment: @estus Interface implementation should make sure that `v1` and `v2` objects are only read but not written. [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/code_Sedgewick/design2Code/list/list.hpp#L31) is a scenario

Comment: It's unclear what 'read' and 'written' is about in your case. `const` doesn't prevent objects from being modified, as the answer explains. Please, provide an example that shows what you're trying to achieve/avoid.

Comment: @estus Query edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to declare this because it would have no effect on anything. `const` in TypeScript **doesn't mean immutable** -- it applies only to a binding, and a function parameter is not an externally-visible binding.

Answer (score 1):

As another answer explains, `const` doesn't prevent objects from being modified in ES6, it only prevents reassignments.

In order to prevent parameter reassignments globally, TSLint [`no-parameter-reassignment` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-parameter-reassignment/) can be used.

In order to prevent object modifications *at runtime*, [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) should be used. This can be enforced *at compilation time* with [`Readonly` mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). However, this won't have any effect if the types are compatible:

```
interface compareTo {
    (v1: Readonly<Square>, v2: Readonly<Square>): number;      
}
const foo: compareTo = (a: Square, b: Square) => {
  a.area = 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Generally, this isn't the responsibility of an interface to tell how function should internally work, it just describes its interface, so it would be:

```
interface compareTo {
    (v1: Square, v2: Square): number;      
}
const foo: compareTo = (a: Readonly<Square>, b: Readonly<Square>) => {
  a.area = 0; // error
  return 1;
}
```

But this will work if types are inferred from generic type, i.e. `a` type isn't specified in `compareTo` implementation:

```
interface compareTo<T = Readonly<Square>> {
    (v1: T, v2: T): number;      
}

const foo: compareTo = (a, b) => {
  a.area = 0; // error
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: interface should be able to tell whether `v1` can be modified. We do this in Java, C. Anyways, `let foo:compareTo = (a: Readonly<Square>, b: Readonly<Square>) => {a = {color: 'red', area: 20}; return 1;}` allows modification

Comment: As I mentioned, an interface only describes function inputs and outputs, not how function works. It's possible to do that with Readonly but not necessarily necessary. JS semantics differs from the C++ example you've linked because objects are passed by reference everywhere in JS, and you can't restrict a developer from shooting into the foot everywhere. Common JS methods like array `map`, `filter`, `sort` aren't typed to prevent object modifications, even though it's rarely a good idea there.

Comment: I do not get all three example in this answer, because `interface Square{readonly color: string; readonly area: number;}` would suffice for not allowing `a.area=0`. I did not get the value-add of using `Readonly<Square>`

Comment: I was under impression that you wanted to omit `readonly` fields in Square and enforce them in `compareTo` only. If you didn't, it still remains unclear what purpose `const` is supposed to serve in your case.

Comment: I would not like to allow something like this... `a = {color: 'white', area: 20};` in the function. `const` helps in such scenario for variables unlike parameters.

Comment: There's no way to prevent this in JS or TS. You can reassign a parameter anywhere. That's a matter of style and personal preference. I don't see a reason to enforce this for a particular function. You can enforce this globally with https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-parameter-reassignment/ as a part of your coding style. I updated the answer.